# Fatal loss of data across OS borders

Tags: usb, images, windows-11, ios

On New Year's Eve I imported images from my iPhone at USB to the Windows 11 platform as I did so many times by:

- select all
- cut
- create new folder
- paste

and it worked. But what I did afterwards was fatal. I pressed Ctrl-Z several times and some times too many. Now the folder and all images were gone. They were neither to be found in the bin nor elsewhere on the Windows system and also not on the iPhone system.

Who is responsible and where are my images possibly to be found?

[My iOS version is >15 and the Win11 is 21H2.]

Comment: [I believe Ctrl+Z in Windows was a joke](https://superuser.com/q/809576/432690). [Always has been](https://superuser.com/q/268159/432690). "Glad" to hear Win11 continues the tradition. Seriously I'm sorry for your loss. Good luck with recovery.

Comment: Check your deleted folder on iOS.

Comment: @Anemoia - this will not hit the Deleted folder. Windows' file copy completely bypasses Apple's control over this [because Windows has no way of correctly mounting an iPhone, it must mount as 'removable media', similar to a USB stick.]

Comment: I can't believe windows has undo in file manager operations. That's totally insane.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski - I just tested Win10 - it also will not allow the user to Undo a 'move' operation if the original disk is no longer present. In fact it will wait until you re-mount the disk, then complete, which is far more than I had expected based on historic behaviour. How the OP managed to do this is really starting to puzzle me now :\

Comment: Does your phone sync your photos to iCloud? Is your phone backed up to iCloud? Do you perform other kinds of backups (e.g. via iTunes)?

Comment: "Who is responsible" - sadly, at the end of the day, the answer is you.  YOU have to take responsibility for your data.  You can't try to blame mishaps on anyone.  Software has bugs in, it's up to you to ensure that the impact of them is minimal to you.

Comment: The good news - is that if you were on a USB device, then deleting is likely to have been a fast delete rather than a hard one - meaning that as long as you've not written more data to the device, then it should be recoverable.

Comment: @akostadinov I can't believe you can't see a reason to offer Undo for file management operations. Have you really never messed up when moving files around? (Deleting to trash is an obvious mini-Undo for deletes, why not also offer Undo for copies, renames, moves, and directory creation?)

Comment: It might be too late for you .. but do check out the `PhotoSync iOS app`. It will let you "push" your files straight to a Windows SMB share over WiFi automatically. Infact, over Wifi6 it's *faster* than USB because Lightning port is only USB2.
For USB-pull based transfers, check out `Downloader Pro`, which also works with SD cards.
Automating this tedious and error-prone manual task is the best way to avert data loss. Speaking from experience :)

Answer (score 16):

Never cut/paste between media [even on the same OS].
It leaves no undo, no way back except file-scavenging tools or a backup.
As you've discovered to your unfortunate cost, Undo makes the new files vanish [not even move to the Trash] without restoring them to their original location [which also did not go to the Trash].
This is a terrible yet long-lived design flaw in the OS.

As to 'who is responsible'… I'd lay that squarely at the feet of Microsoft for allowing you to do it in the first place. macOS [& as far as I'm aware, nix,] have no equivalent command. The closest equivalent is 'move' which completes a copy then deletes the original - both of which are then undoable.*

As you can't file-scavenge on iOS, that leaves a Windows tool as your recovery option. Make sure to save any files rescued to a new drive or you risk further overwriting your recovery attempt & avoid using your drive until recovery is complete. [Recover shift-deleted file in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/283000/recover-shift-deleted-file-in-windows) has some suggestions for recovery tools.

**After comments*
I've just tested Apple's 'move' to & from a removable drive. If Undo is not possible [drive unmounted], it will either grey out the menu item or start but then error without completing [depending on which way the file was transferred]. In short, it will not let you accidentally Undo the write unless it can be fully undone on both drives.

I've also just tested this on Win10. It also doesn't allow the Undo if the original removable disk is missing.
This would seem to be the wanted situation, preventing the old 'broken' undo from deleting files. I definitely recall this happening in the past, but it's been many years since I used Windows frequently, so idk if this is a recent change, a user setting, or whether it's just possible to easily confuse it.

Comment: The UI "cut" and "paste" operations produce a move on Windows as well, which does copy and then delete the original.  It's the "both of which are then undoable" which is the problem -- obviously this is not always true (consider when the original location, on removeble media, has been unplugged).  The flaw lies in an "undo" operation which does not test whether the "undelete the original" step succeeds before moving on to "remove the copy".

Comment: macOS Finder does have a CMD-Z undo function, however it frequently becomes disabled, likely to prevent this exact thing from happening.

Comment: @BenVoigt - I've jst tested Apple's 'move' to & from a removable drive. If Undo is not possible [drive unmounted], it will either grey out the menu item or start but then error without completing [depending on which way the file was transferred]. In short, it will not let you accidentally Undo the write unless it can be fully undone on both drives.

Comment: Isn't it possible to file-scavenge on iOS by jailbreaking the device first? Yes, it's definitely not the easiest approach, but if it's the only way to save some precious files, it might be worth the hassle. (It would certainly be perfectly possible on Android, but I don't have any recent experience with this on iOS.)

Comment: @TooTea - there are purported file scavengers for iOS that run from Mac or Win. idk of one that's successful though. I just tried a demo on my own phone & it couldn't decrypt.